# TypeScript: infer return type of array based on input array elements

Tags: typescript, type-inference, inferred-type

I have a function which can have multiple parameters of type `Node` or `Relationship` or `undefined`. It has the following signature:

```js
export function useFormat(...elements: Array<Node | Relationship | undefined>) {
    const formattedElements: Array<FormattedNode | FormattedRelationship | undefined> = [];
    // do formatting...
    return formattedElements;
 }
```

I call it as a React Hook and do some formatting based on the given element type. Then I return a new array with basically the same elements in a different format: `Array<FormattedNode | FormattedRelationship | undefined>`.

I would like to know if it is possible for TypeScript to infer the type of each element in the returned array based on the same element in the original array `elements`.

For example: the first element in the original array `elements[0]` is a `Node`, so first element of the returned array `formattedElements[0]` will be a `FormattedNode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should use overloads here:

```js
type Relationship = {
    type: 'Relationship'
}

type FormattedRelationship = {
    type: 'FormattedRelationship'
}

type CustomNode = {
    type: 'CustomNode '
}

type FormattedNode = {
    type: 'FormattedNode'
}


type Input = CustomNode | Relationship | undefined
type Output = FormattedNode | FormattedRelationship | undefined

type Return<T extends Input> =
    T extends CustomNode
    ? 0
    : T extends Relationship
    ? 1
    : T extends undefined
    ? 2
    : 3

function useFormat<
    T extends Input,
    U extends T[],
    R extends {
        0: FormattedNode[],
        1: FormattedRelationship[],
        2: undefined[],
        3: never
    }[Return<T>]>(...elements: [T, ...U]): R
function useFormat<
    T extends Input,
    U extends T[],
    >(...elements: [T, ...U]) {
    const formattedElements: Output[] = [];
    // do formatting...
    return formattedElements
}
const result = useFormat({ type: 'Relationship' }) // FormattedRelationship
const result2 = useFormat({ type: 'CustomNode ' }) // FormattedNode
```

Much readable format:

```js
function useFormat<
    T extends CustomNode,
    U extends T[]>(...elements: [T, ...U]): FormattedNode[]
function useFormat<
    T extends Relationship,
    U extends T[]>(...elements: [T, ...U]): FormattedRelationship[]
function useFormat<
    T extends undefined,
    U extends T[]>(...elements: [T, ...U]): undefined[]
function useFormat<
    T extends Input,
    U extends T[],
    >(...elements: [T, ...U]) {
    const formattedElements: Output[] = [];
    // do formatting...
    return formattedElements
}
const result = useFormat({ type: 'Relationship' }) // FormattedRelationship
const result2 = useFormat({ type: 'CustomNode ' }) // FormattedNode
```

**UPDATE**

```js
type Relationship = {
    type: 'Relationship'
}

type FormattedRelationship = {
    type: 'FormattedRelationship'
}

type CustomNode = {
    type: 'CustomNode '
}

type FormattedNode = {
    type: 'FormattedNode'
}


type Input = CustomNode | Relationship | undefined
type Output = FormattedNode | FormattedRelationship | undefined

type MapPredicate<T> =
    T extends Input
    ? T extends CustomNode
    ? FormattedNode
    : T extends Relationship
    ? FormattedRelationship
    : T extends undefined
    ? undefined
    : never : never

type Mapped<
    Arr extends Array<unknown>,
    Result extends Array<unknown> = []
    > = Arr extends []
    ? []
    : Arr extends [infer H]
    ? [...Result, MapPredicate<H>]
    : Arr extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail]
    ? Mapped<[...Tail], [...Result, MapPredicate<Head>]>
    : Readonly<Result>;

function useFormat<
    T extends Input,
    U extends T[],
    >(...elements: [...U]): Mapped<U>
function useFormat<
    T extends Input,
    U extends T[],
    >(...elements: [...U]): any {
    const formattedElements: Output[] = [];
    // do formatting...
    return formattedElements
}
const result = useFormat({ type: 'Relationship' }) // FormattedRelationship
const result2 = useFormat({ type: 'CustomNode ' }, { type: 'Relationship' }) // FormattedNode
```

Please keep in mind, these types are not 100% safe because I used `any` in order to make it compatible with overload.

Second, it is also better to define more than 1 overload. Since array types is mutable, some times it is hard to write type safe functions without using type assertions or `any`.

Now, you know all drawbacks.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShA2BDYBLA9gOwM4AsVigF4oBvAWACgpqpRIAuKAcjiVU13ycoF9LK60AGJoATgFtkwCABNWydNjwFi5KjUGMmIiVNnz2Srr34VBUAMIBXLMDTiAcmhnRVlGrXAQt12-acuzCYUAl5QOpLA0jIBrqTuGl5aEXoxzhDcFHwhOeYAkhhgVsBEljZ2julQAD6wCAocyjVQVhguAGYoGLKhkFAA8sVFJcQpUbKxzWPRBoqcBLWtHV09uWEAsohgAAqisigAxsgQADwAKgB8RAnUZ1AQAB7SbVhQBcM3UAD8UHePzzJXr4KrFPj9phN0p9GH8nhAXnU2HNlGDwmJIjN6oZ5tDfvc4QilhBOt0ZKiiSTVh5GN0AG4QURQGkQemiUzmTZgSAyE6fACCokZ-3hgKgAtEiBAJ1aAGsMGgAO4YC4AGk%20cCwVngJWFCPFkulGDliuVpQA2gBdT5XYji-EA16W1FO9TURh23Wis1ddoMqAACStru%20UDNADoIxqtcAVVBObt9kdpCd-Rcg9SxYL7SLHT6-f6IIgZLGI2G84yzogUPB0zQfpzuSdwxHK9WLbHm2Go9rY-G9jJDscU4WZGmLri4EXMPApd3gBcANymdqtA6GFpYCBjXnB2EOt6FYpq4MAVWzCLOluPHguAApSwgIOJ4cAsIxOyeLQBKRgN2QnE9xwoFcMDXRQNy3dFkB3Dw9xzA9hmvGgz09V5L3ba17wjR9nwwV931LT8fygRAMBAeJgwODgSnaKDxhkABReAnxfN8BiGYpLXNC0l2DAB6PioBkNAoFo3Qoi6ABzUtPj2YArFEDBRLo6ImJYvCsGCKjsBKPZNW1UobEg8TbxITwGGYWZGi4KAeC-KABLRcTMSRaywEobTbCgPTowAJkMzcxlM8zvGYYF-CqJhbNjMzNEsrFkRsuyHMEiE0hcIA)

If you want to know more about literal array mappings or tuples, you can refer to my [blog](https://catchts.com/tuples#map)

**UPDATE - without rest**

```js
type Relationship = {
    type: 'Relationship'
}

type FormattedRelationship = {
    type: 'FormattedRelationship'
}

type CustomNode = {
    type: 'CustomNode '
}

type FormattedNode = {
    type: 'FormattedNode'
}


type Input = CustomNode | Relationship | undefined
type Output = FormattedNode | FormattedRelationship | undefined

type MapPredicate<T> =
    T extends Input
    ? T extends CustomNode
    ? FormattedNode
    : T extends Relationship
    ? FormattedRelationship
    : T extends undefined
    ? undefined
    : never : never

type Mapped<
    Arr extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>,
    Result extends Array<unknown> = []
    > = Arr extends []
    ? []
    : Arr extends [infer H]
    ? [...Result, MapPredicate<H>]
    : Arr extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail]
    ? Mapped<[...Tail], [...Result, MapPredicate<Head>]>
    : Readonly<Result>;

function useFormat<
    T extends Input,
    U extends ReadonlyArray<T>,
    >(elements: [...U]): Mapped<U>
function useFormat<
    T extends Input,
    U extends T[],
    >(elements: U): any {
    const formattedElements: Output[] = [];
    // do formatting...
    return formattedElements
}
const result = useFormat([{ type: 'Relationship' }]) // FormattedRelationship
const result2 = useFormat([{ type: 'CustomNode ' }, { type: 'Relationship' }]) // FormattedNode
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShA2BDYBLA9gOwM4AsVigF4oBvAWACgpqpRIAuKAcjiVU13ycoF9LK60AGJoATgFtkwCABNWydNjwFi5KjUGMmIiVNnz2Srr34VBUAMIBXLMDTiAcmhnRVlGrXAQt12-acuzCYUAl5QOpLA0jIBrqTuGl5aEXoxzhDcFHwhOeYAkhhgVsBEljZ2julQAD6wCAocyjVQVhguAGYoGLKhkFAA8sVFJcQpUbKxzWPRBoqcBLWtHV09uWEAsohgAAqisigAxsgQADwAKgB8RAnUZ1AQAB7SbVhQBcM3UAD8UHePzzJXr4KrFPj9phN0p9GH8nhAXnU2HNlGDwmJIjN6oZ5tDfvc4QilhBOt0ZKiiSTVh5GN0AG4QURQGkQemiUzmTZgSAyE6fACCokZ-3hgLqiBkmHgIAFokQIBOrQA1hg0AB3DAXAA0nzgWCs8BKwoRMrlCowyrVGtKAG0ALqfK7EGX4gGvO2o93qaiMZ1G0XWrrtBlQAAS9q93yg1oAdLHdfrgJqoJzdvsjtITiGLuHqVBfQT-YHgyGIOKk7Ho0XGWdECh4DmaD9OdyTjHYzW67ak23o-GDUmU3sZIdjpnSzJsxdcXBxZL5X3gBcANymdqtA6GFpYCBjXkR2Gut6FYraiMAVRdIteM4lGClJvll1PHguAAoEBBxPDgFhGD2z7aACUjDNrIJxnlOFBrhgG6KFuO7osge4eAeV5HsMz40BefqvGcdqYdQb4fl%20GA-owZ7AVAiAYCA8QRgcHAlO0iHjDIACi8Cft%20v4DEMxR2jatorhGAD0IlQBKUDMboURdAA5hWnx7MAViiBgUksdEHFcaRWDBAx2AlHseoGqUNgITJr7WiQngMMwsyNFwUA8EBUBiWiMmYkijlgJQBm2FAxkJgATGZ25jFZNmaMwwL%20FUTDOUmUVJPZWLIk5LmAW54kQmkLhAA)

This is the case when you need `[...U]` instead of `U`. It helps to infer every element in the array. Try to replace `[...U]` with `U` inside overload

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! I think I forgot to mention an important part: I call the function with multiple different elements in one call. For example: useFormat(sourceNode, relationship1, targetNode) or useFormat(node1, node2, node3, node4). So I do not specify the type within the call.

Comment: My fn does not allow different types. SHould I allow it?

Comment: What is the reason for using an overload?

Comment: Because conditional return types does not work in ts, at least in a way you expect

Comment: One more question: why are you using `[...U]` as type of the rest parameter `...elements` instead of simply `U`?

Comment: @zrkl on early stage draft, I had two arguments (a:T, ...elements:[T, ...U]). Then I removed first parameter and forgot about `[...U]`. Feel free to use just `U`.

Comment: What would need to be changed to use an simple array as parameter `elements` instead of a rest parameter `...elements` array/tuple?